# return null value when reading from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

attributes of the class supplierClass returns null. Datasnapshot assigns correctly to the attributes. However the list does not provide the right values. only material name works

1. screenshot 1- snapshot value  [image]
2. screenshot 2- output screen  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsXh1.png)

Code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_suppliers,container,false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.suppliersList);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("suppliers");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        list= new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter=new recyclerAdapter(getActivity(),list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    supplierClass sc=dataSnapshot.getValue(supplierClass.class);
                    list.add(sc);
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        return view;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `supplierClass` class.

Comment: the problem was the class supplierClass. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

attributes names should be same as on firebase DB

```
String sName, equipmentName, materialName; 
        public String getsName() {
            return sName;
        }
    
        public String getEquipmentName() {
            return equipmentName;
        }
    
        public String getMaterialName() {
            return materialName;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).